# Inherit signals and slots from a base class in Qt

Tags: c++, inheritance, qt5

I have created:

```
class A : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

public signals:
   Q_SIGNAL void mySignal();
};
```

And I would like to derive:

```
class B : public A
{
   //Some added functionality
};
```

And still be able to connect mySignal() emitted by B (which it inherited from A) to a slot in my QMainWindow:

```
B b;
connect(&b, SIGNAL(mySignal()), this, SLOT(aSlot()));
```

Currently this method results in "multiple definition of "A::disconnected()" and the compiler points me to the moc file here:

```
void A::disconnected()
{
    QMetaObject::activate(this, &staticMetaObject, 0, nullptr);
}
```

What is the problem here?

I have done my research but what I found seems to be on different types of inheritance patterns and I don't understand Qt enough to port conclusions here.

Edit: I had stupidly forgotten the & in my original post, thanks Scheff's cat - I've updated my problem.

Comment: Please, don't use Qt4 style signal/slot connections anymore. Qt5 has something better. (I'm quite sure that I already did things like exposed in your snippets in Qt5.) FYI: [New Signal Slot Syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax). Nevertheless... Did you try whether it helps if you add `Q_OBJECT` to `class B`?

Comment: By the way... For `B b;` it has to be `connect(&b, ...` (You are missing the address operator but `connect()` expects a _pointer_ to a widget as first argument always.)

Comment: Facepalm, sorry I fixed the missing ampersand and thanks. It still doesn't work though even with the new connect syntax: Multiple definition of: void A::disconnected(). I've updated my question, thanks for the help

Comment: Nevermind, another stupid reason which comes from my ignorance of Qt's inner workings! I had defined the signal in my source file, see my answer... Thanks for spotting the missing ampersand and for the advice on connect() :)

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who have the same problem as this one, check your source file for a potential definition of A::mySignal()... I had created an empty definition of the function, as usual, whereas apparently MOC creates one for us. Resulting in multiple definitions.